# Cannot find cap file on home folder

Tags: files

I have run `aircrack-ng` on ubuntu 13.10 that i was download from `ubuntu software centre`.The problem is after running `aireplay-ng` to catch the cap file,i cannot find the `cap file` on home folder.On other version ubuntu like 12.04 the file is always in home folder.So can anybody tell me why and where can i get that file on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
locate *.cap
```

that will list all .cap files.

for example :

```
august@august-OEM:~$ locate *.cap
/pentest/fuzzers/spike/data/halflife1.cap
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `find` command , type this in your terminal .If you have the filename which you have used for capturing

```
find / -type f -iname "halflife1.cap"
```

for example:

```
august@august-OEM:~$ sudo find / -type f -iname "halflife1.cap"
[sudo] password for august: 
/pentest/fuzzers/spike/data/halflife1.cap
```